# Java Web Start and allowArraySyntax is not set

Tags: java, java-web-start

ref: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6434149

My problem is that `sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax` is **not** set to **true** when using java webstart (javaws) later than 1.6.0_05 (JRE is 1.6.0_14).

I have tried:

> set JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

or manually specifying it:

> javaws.exe -J-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true ...

But when outputting the system property I only get null (if later than 1.6.0_05).

I really need web start to work, any ideas?

---

Some setup information:

Weblogic 9.2 on Windows (server)

Java client also running on Windows

Comment: Side Note: JWS has a huge security vulnerability in Java 1.6.0_19 and earlier.  You *really* should be using 1.6.0_20 or newer.

Comment: Could you not just correct the faulty code?

Comment: What's the point of using JavaWS when you need to specify arguments to the launcher for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some strange characters at the beginning of my jnlp-file, javaws, apparently,  did a second launch (this could be seen where the java-console started twice) where the vmargs were lost...

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue myself with a weblogic service and I cannot update the server platform at this time. Looks like this VM setting can be passed in through the JNLP file in the j2se or java tag

```
java-vm-args="-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true"
```

But there seems to be a java 6 bug that is not passing this setting on to the JVM, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6953324. This is said to be fixed in java release 6u23 and seems to work in the 6u45 or so.

I found another webstart article stating that this setting can be done in a Property tag but have not found that to work.